# How do I make button that adds UITableViewCell to a UITableView?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

This question is pretty self explanatory. I have looked all over Youtube and Google to find the answer but everyone is focused on making a UITableViewCell from interface builder but I want to have a feature that lets the user make their own.

Answer (score 1):

The basic approach to take is this:

1. Create your button and set its' action to a function in your class (let's call the function `addTableViewCell`)
2. In `addTableViewCell`, you create a new entry in your data source.
3. Call `[tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths: withRowAnimation:]` or `[tableView reloadData]` in order to get it to show up.

Let me know if you need more details.